# How do I create a type with another type nested inside it?

Tags: typescript

How could I write these two types to reduce code duplication

```
export type props = {
  data: {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
    d: number;
  }[];
};

export type result = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      a: string;
      b: string;
      c: boolean;
      d: number;
    }[];
  };
};
```

So that I could write something like (pseudocode):

```
export type props = {
  data: {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
    d: number;
  }[];
};

export type result = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      ...props.data
    }[];
  };
};
```

Comment: Why not extract `{ a: string; b: string; c: boolean; d: number; }` as a separate type?

Comment: Side note: The overwhelmingly-common convention in TypeScript is that object types like these are initially-capped, so `Props` and `Result` rather than `props` and `result`. You don't have to follow convention, but it makes it easier for other people to read your code (for instance, on Stack Overflow) if you do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two answers for you:

#### Create a new interface for the common bits

For instance, here I've called it `Data` though a more inspired name would be better:

```typescript
interface Data {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
    d: number;
}
export type props = {
  data: Data[];
};

export type result = {
  foo: {
    bar: Data[];
  };
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUMg5OALmQGcwpQBzAbn0ICNSKqQ6GCFTGB7XgDYQ4IeoWQATUiACuAW0bR6AX1wQAHgAdeUMMjABPTSk1RemssgC8OBhIwk0DgNoBdFfTVadew8eRQEGQyAno2eAQw-KQRTHBQpOiYbmLIyh64QA)

#### Refer to the other type

I wouldn't recommend this unless you have a good reason for it, but you can refer to the other type:

```typescript
export type props = {
  data: {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
    d: number;
  }[];
};

export type result = {
  foo: {
    bar: props["data"];
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  };
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcxQmAznAvHAbwCg44ATAQxgoC5CTS5a4sYoBLAOwHMBuB0gCM6rDj36M4AYzqCIEADbAKnCYzJ1OAVwC2g4FDUBfANoBdfkf5FQkWAmSoowLFoXx8xUgDN5dL4yCFFB06JhYJgBElNSRFkQA9AmSjAB66RmZGQxWRLlAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom type for your data:

```
type Data = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
    d: number;
}
```

And then you can utilize this type:

```
export type props = {
  data: Data[];
};

export type result = {
  foo: {
    bar: Data[];
  };
};
```